# how to mast match all args pass in array in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

Here term gives result if one of all args (1,2) match and i need all args must have in degree.id of user
here i have data like this

```
"id": 66,
"name": null,
"degrees": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "BCA",
    },{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "MCA",
    }
]
```

So i need that, if BCA and MCA both degree exists only those record will be arrive in result

```
$term = new \Elastica\Query\Terms();
$term->setTerms('degrees.id', array('1','2'));

return $boolQuery->addMust($term);
```

Comment: you need a results where degrees.name has both BCA and MCA ?

Comment: yes, i want that but id wise

Comment: it's still not clear, what id wise ? give an example

Comment: means all provided certificates ids must user have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're making with your `setTerms` is actually an `OR` on `degrees` field.

To make an `AND` query, I recommend to use the `Elastica\Query\BoolQuery` class as follow :

```
$BCAQuery = new Elastica\Query\Term();
$BCAQuery->setTerm('degree.id', 1);

$MCAQuery = new Elastica\Query\Term();
$MCAQuery->setTerm('degree.id', 2);

$boolQuery = new BoolQuery();
$boolQuery->addMust($BCAQuery);
$boolQuery->addMust($MCAQuery);
```

Remember that if `degrees` is mapped as `nested` to use you bool query with `Elastica\Query\Nested`

```
$degreesQuery = new Elastica\Query\Nested();
$degreeQuery->setPath('degrees');
$degreesQuery->setQuery($boolQuery);
```